# Give a user permission to another user's folder

Tags: permissions, git

Currently I have a user called "git", which has access to its home folder and all folders inside (they are git repos). I need to create another user with access to just one of the folders of the "git" user.

When I googled it all answer point to changing the ownership of the folder to the new user, but I'm afraid I might screw up the existing user by doing that.

I tried by setting the permissions to the folder to 664, which is supposed to give read permission to "others", but I get permission denied when I login with the new user and try to `cd` into the folder.

Can someone tell me how to do this properly?

Cheers

Comment: permissions = 664 .. first number is owner; second is group, third is everyone else.  the simple answer is in the middle; ie. create a group, add both users to the group and let the group have read/write/execute permissions on files that the whole group are allowed to.  trying looking there, or call out if still stuck.  if a group isn't to have permissions; those folders/files will be assigned to users & not the group.  chrgrp, groupadd ....

Comment: @guiverc, put it as an answer. It's complete.

Answer (score 1):

permissions = 664 .. first number is owner; second is group, third is everyone else.

The simple answer is in the middle; ie. create a group, add both users to the group and let the group have read/write/execute permissions on files that the whole group are allowed to.

Trying looking there, or call out if you're still stuck. If a group isn't to have permissions; those folders/files will be assigned to users & not the group. chrgrp, groupadd ....  (more permission options exist; this are the 1970s unix permissions so heaps of doco is available)